# Upper triangular matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of a square matrix A $\in$ $M_n$ with the following properties.

(a) entii(A) $\neq$ 0 for each i $\leq$ n but A is not invertible.

(b) entii(A) = 0 for each i $\leq$ n but A is invertible.

I know that for an upper triangular matrix the diagonal entries must not equal zero in order for the matrix to be invertible, so I have no ideas for examples, please help!

Comment: What do you mean by entii(A)?

Comment: ith diagonal entry of matrix A

Comment: But is A upper triangular?

Comment: An upper triangular matrix has diagonal entries...

Comment: But are you supposing that elements below the diagonal are 0?

Comment: in the question, it says for i less than or equal to n and A is a nxn square matrix.

Comment: So you are saying that the elements of the diagonal are 0 from 1 to $n$, but you are not saying that the elements under the diagonal are 0. Do you see my point?

Comment: You may mean entij(A) with $j \leq i \leq n$?

Comment: The only thing given in this questions is that the diagonal entries of A are not equal to zero and the second part they are equal to zero. I guess don't worry about if it is an upper triangular matrix, that is just what we are studying so I figured it would be an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: That is exactly the question that is given to me, so I am kind of confused by it too.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that a matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if it $|A|\neq0$, so the matrices that verifies the conditions you are asking for cannot be triangular matrices (can you prove it?)

Now, let's see what happens if $A$ is not required to be triangular.

Set, for example, $n=2$:

(a) Consider $ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &1 \\ 1 &1 \end{pmatrix} $. Then $ |A|=0 $ so $A$ is not invertible and ent11($A$)=ent22($A$)=$1\neq0$.

(b) Consider now $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 1 &0 \end{pmatrix} $. Then $ |A|=1 $ so $A$ is invertible and ent11($A$)=ent22($A$)=$0$.

Do you see a general argument for an arbitrary $n$?